# Union of sets of continuous functions is countable

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, functions, metric-spaces

> Let $E = C(I; \mathbb{R})$ be the space of continuous functions from $I$ to $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with the uniform metric. Let $$A=\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty A_n$$where $A_n$ denotes the set of continuous functions $g : I \to \mathbb{R}$ which are linear on each interval of the form $[k/2^n, (k+1)/2^n]$, and satisfy $$g(k/2^n)\in \mathbb{Q} \;\; \text{for all} \;\; k \in \{0,1,\dots, 2^n \}.$$ Show that $A$ is countable.

I have the following hint: Show that each set $A_n$ is countable, by surjecting it onto $\mathbb{Q}^{1+2^n}$. I know that a countable union of countable sets is countable, but I'm unsure of how to set up the surjection leading towards the result of each $A_n$ being countable.

Please help!

Comment: Hint: Say $g \in A_n$. To _fully_ specify $g$, what pieces of information do you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It suffices to show that each $A_{n}$ is countable. Map each $f\in A_{n}$ into a coordinate $\left(f\left(\dfrac{0}{2^{n}}\right),...,f\left(\dfrac{k}{2^{n}}\right),...,f\left(\dfrac{2^{n}}{2^{n}}\right)\right)\in{\bf{Q}}\times\cdots\times{\bf{Q}}$. Such a map is injective. For $f,g\in A_{n}$, on a subinterval $[k/2^{n},(k+1)/2^{n}]$, since they are linear joining the endpoints, if they map the same values at the endpoints, they are the same on that interval. Apply successively this argument to each subinterval, we find that $f=g$.